# Adding existing canvas to a div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a problem with adding existing canvas to a div dynamically via jQuery. Also I try numerous options to append this but any one works.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="a"> 
    <div id="b"></div> 
    <div id="c" class="c"> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if($('.myDivIfLoad').text().length >= 0)
    {
        //$('canvas[class="canvasClass"]').appendTo($('.c')); // doesn't work
        //$('canvas[class="canvasClass"]').append($('.c')); // doesn't work
        //var canv= $('canvas[class="canvasClass"]'); //doesn't work
        //document.getElementById('c').appendChild(canv)        // doesn't work
        $('canvas.canvasClass').appendTo('.c')
        $(function()
        { 
            $(".a").hover(function()
            { 
                $(".a").stop(true, false).animate({right: "0" }, 800, 'easeOutQuint' ); 
            }, function()
            { 
                $(".a").stop(true, false).animate({right: "-245" }, 800, 'easeInQuint' ); 
            },1000); 
        }); 
    }
});
```

If someone could help me I will be very grateful!

## Edit

If it depends in my code I based on this tutorial: http://w3lessons.info/demo/sliding-facebook-likebox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four things:

1. <s>In CSS, *identifiers* (`id` values, class names) [cannot start with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), so the selector `.3` is invalid (as is the selector `#1`, etc.).</s> *(You've said below that those aren't your real `id`s and classes, and that your real ones don't start with digits.)*

   <s>Consider starting your `id`s and class names with a letter so your selectors are valid.</s>
2. Your `appendTo`, not `append`, was the right way to go, it was just the selector that was the problem.
3. `canvas[class="canvasClass"]` looks for a `canvas` with **exactly** the class `canvasClass` and **no others**. It'll match `<canvas class="canvasClass">..</canvas>"` but not `<canvas class="foo canvasClass">..</canvas>` or similar. The best way to select by class is a class selector, `canvas.canvasClass`, which will match any element with that class (even if it also has others).
4. This is suspect: `$('.myDivIfLoad').val().length`. The class suggests it's a `div`, but `div`s don't have *values*. They have contents. You may want `.text().length` or `.html().length` or `.children().length` or `.contents().length` depending on what your goal with that line is.

Answer (score 0):

You can append it like this for example using [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method (instead of [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)):

```
$('canvas[class="canvasClass"]').appendTo('.c');
```

or better

```
$('canvas.canvasClass').appendTo('.c');
```

Or

```
var canv = $('canvas.canvasClass');
$('.c').append(canv);
```

Or even if you really want

```
var canv = $('canvas.canvasClass');
document.getElementById('c').appendChild(canv[0]);
```

Comment: Hm.. you are right. Then probably `'canvas[class="canvasClass"]'` selectors selects nothing.

Comment: I try all options which You suggest but no one works for me..
canvas[class="canvasClass"] return canvas, but it doesn't append to the div.